# Google sign_in_failed error in a Flutter app using firebase auth

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm developing a Flutter mobile app and testing things on an Android emulator.

I'm using Firebase to handle auth logic.

I created a service

```dart
class AuthService {
  Future<void> googleLogin() async {
    try {
      final googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

      if (googleUser == null) return;

      final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      final authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken
      );

      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // handle the error
    }
  }
}
```

that I call on the press of a button. I do authenticate with my Google account, however, then the terminal shows this error

> PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null, null)

I read online that this is due to missing `SHA` credentials in my firebase project. So I generated these credentials using `./gradlew signingReport` from the `android` directory within the project. I then added the certificates (both `SHA-1` and `SHA-256` to the android app in my flutter project.

I downloaded again the Google services file provided by Firebase, run `flutter clean` and `flutter run` but I'm still facing the very same issue when I try to login.

Why is this happening? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to add a support email id in your Firebase console like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!

Comment: happy to help you :)